# Can monit have a date and/or time that it restarts vs just uptime duration?

Tags: ubuntu, monit

If I want monit to restart a process every 7 days, I can use

```
https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#PROCESS-UPTIME-TESTING
if uptime > 7 days then restart
```

However, does monit have a built in way to restart at a certain date/time? For example:

```
restart every saturday night at midnight
```

Does this exist?
If not how do others handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answer of [vesquam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673534/vesquam), but to me it's better to specify the crontab entries in Monit itself, using an extra `check program` statement specifically for the restarting:

```
check program mariadb_restart with path "/bin/monit restart mariadb"
    with timeout 600 seconds
    every "0 0 * * 0-6"
    if status != 0 then alert
```

Pros: It's all in one place, you can get alerts when the restart fails.. etc

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but if should someone have the same question I'd like to share my input on it.

I think that this should be better handled by a cron job calling monit to restart the service.

For example we would like the deamon of mariadb to be restarted every  Saturday night at midnight. I would first define the monit descriptor as so:

```
 check process mariadb with pidfile /var/lib/mysql/mariadb.pid
   group database
   start program = "/bin/systemctl start mariadb" with timeout 150 seconds
   stop program = "/bin/systemctl stop mariadb"
   if failed
      host 127.0.0.1
      port 3306 protocol
      mysql
   then restart
```

And in the crontab I would have this entry for restarting on Sunday midnight:

```
0 0 * * 0 monit restart mariadb
```

I find that keeping cron doing the scheduled task is best because it's the goto tool for the task. That way, if someone new comes to the environment he'll know right away where to change the time when the service is restarted.